# jQuery Mobile Slider not rendering correctly in dialog

Tags: html, dialog, jquery-mobile, slider

I’m using a jQuery mobile slider in a **JQM dialog** but it’s not being rendered properly, it’s most noticeable in safari and chrome. It renders fine in a standard JQM page.

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="Dialog1"> 
<div data-role="header"> <h1> Dialog</h1> </div>
<div data-role="content">
     <label for="slider-2">Input slider:</label>
     <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider-2" 
                   value="25" min="0" max="100"  />
</div>
<div data-role="footer"><h3>Footer</h3></div>
</div>
```

Here’s a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ9KA/1/) illustrating the issue, if you click the “open dialog” button the slider isn’t rendered correctly but if you click the “open as page” it is.

I’ve tried calling `.slider()` and `.slider(‘refresh’)` in the `pageshow` event but it doesn’t seem to make a difference.

Comment: It seems to render fine for me with Chrome. Shows the same as in http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/forms-all.html . What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is only when it's in a dialog. In the documentation the slider is in a standard page. Take a look at the jsfiddle i linked to.

Comment: OK I basically solved the problem, I can't post the answer yet since I'm still a little short on the required rep (it seems that you need a 100 rep to self answer within 8 hours).

Comment: Ah, the small cute slidder instead of the input box! I didn't notice it initially

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an easier way to fix that:

```
<input type="number" data-type="range" name="slider" id="slider-0" value="0" min="0" max="100">
```

Its an number type but with an range data-type. Figured it out by playing around with the code.
Works fine so far!

**Anyway it's fixed in the latest version 1.0.1!**

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely more elegant than my solution. Good to know that it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Just saw that 1.0.1 was released yesterday, so i guess make that current release.

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.0 now and calling trigger('create') on a node containing a range input, actually gives me two sliders side by side on occasion (the original one alongside the jqm one). Not sure what I'm doing wrong (cannot reproduce the error by adding the slider by hand in the javascript console). However, this did the job

Answer (score 0):

OK I sort of solved the problem, though the solution is not to pretty and is a bit of a hack.

I realized that the problem is only when the slider is on a dialog, so what I’m doing is setting the `data-role` of the page I want as a dialog to `page`, then in my JavaScript I call the `dialog()` method on that page to initialize it as a dialog widget. The problem is that when you change to the page next the x in the corner (close button) doesn’t get rendered, so I’m manually creating the styles and markup for it.

Here’s the code I’m using

```
 $('#progWiz').dialog().find('a:first')
  .addClass('ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-a' + 
        ' ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow')
    .attr({ 'title': 'close', 'data-theme': 'a' })
     .empty()
     .append('<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">' +
            ' <span class="ui-btn-text">Close</span>' +
         '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow"></span></span>');
```

If someone has a better solution I'd be happy to hear, in the meantime I'll just do this and hopefully this get's fixed in the next release of JQM.

Answer (score 0):

I also seek solution. I have two Sliders in dialog.

Code below is not solution but workaround I did for my problem. Hope it helps someone.

Problem is in Android Phones it does not create input boxes on left showing value of slider.

I handled that by hiding the original input type slide and adding a text box above the slider.

On slide change event I change the Text Box Value. And as I dont want Keyboard operations , I have disabled the text box.

Code Below.

```
   <script> 
$("#slider-0").change(function(event, ui) {
                $('#thicknessBox').val($(this).val());
    });
</script>
   <label for="slider-1">Thickness:</label>
   <input type="text" id="thicknessBox" name="slider-1" disabled="disabled" ></input>
   <input data-role="none" style="display:none;" type="range" 
    id="slider-0" value="1" min="1" max="10"  />
```

Im not proud of it but atleast now it looks and behaves like slider outside the dialog.

Looking forward to better solution.

Comment: Did you try my workaround? it's also not the prettiest but it seems to be working and you only need to call the code once (instead of binding to an event).